# Force Caption Below the Picture

Tags: captions

I am trying to place the caption below the figure and I have read some similar problems and tried the solutions thereof though to no avail. So I post the code here, asking for your kind assistance.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{The picture shows the evolutionary process of Covid-19 spread\cite{5}.}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{two.png}\label{pictwo}

 \end{figure}
```

Comment: by default the caption just comes where you put it, so put it after \includegraphics if you want the caption after the graphic

Comment: It is fixed, thanks a lot

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comment.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the caption just comes where you put it, so put it after `\includegraphics` if you want the caption after the graphic.